# Запрос к ВК API приводит к ошибке: Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Я пишу бота для отправки записей из Telegram в ВК
Пишу на Python 3.5
Что бы отправить сообщение использую данную функцию:

```
def post(message):
    print(urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?from_group=1&owner_id='+owner_id+'&message='+message+'&access_token='+access_token+'&v=5.62').read())
```

В ответ API ВК мне шлёт ошибку с ссылкой для подтверждения действий:

```
{"error":{"error_code":17,"error_msg":"Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser 246620520","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"},{"key":"from_group","value":"1"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"(Группа)"},{"key":"message","value":"TestForBot"},{"key":"v","value":"5.62"}],"redirect_uri":"https:\\/\\/m.vk.com\\/login?act=security_check&api_hash=(Хэш)"}}
```

Запись после запроса к API не появилась. Я попробовал подставить костылей и сделал всё следующим образом:

```
def post(message):
    print('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?from_group=1&owner_id='+owner_id+'&message='+message+'&access_token='+access_token+'&v=5.62')
    validate=str(urllib.request.urlopen(Запрос к API).read())
    print(validate)
    for i in range(len(validate)-16):
        if validate[i:i+16:]=='"redirect_uri":"':
            i+=16
            validate_url=''
            while validate[i]!='"':
                if validate[i]!='\\':
                    validate_url+=validate[i]
                i+=1
            break
    requests.get(validate_url)
```

То есть, я сделал так, что бы Python после запроса к API открывал ту ссылку, которую надо было открыть для подтверждения действий. Опять ничего.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Если я отправляю запрос через браузер, то всё нормально проходит, без ошибок. Только через Python такое происходит.

Использую Питон 3.5

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/need_validation

Comment: Нужно открывать эту ссылку руками в самом настоящем браузера и теми же руками выполнить требования, которые будут там написаны.

Comment: И никак этот процесс не автоматизировать?

Answer (score 2):

**Довольно редко** эта ошибка означает именно то, что [там написано](https://vk.com/dev/need_validation). То бишь, вероятнее всего, открытие ссылки в браузере не решит проблему и ошибка будет появляться вновь и вновь, не давая вам вызывать какие-либо методы из-под используемого вами токена. Открытие ссылки в браузере может помочь только в том случае, если вы обращаетесь к API с того же IP, с которого пользователь авторизован во ВКонтакте.

А вот **наиболее вероятная** причина возникновения этой ошибки — это отсутствие двухфакторной авторизации на аккаунте. То есть вам надо привязать номер телефона к профилю ВКонтакте и настроить там вход с помощью одноразовых кодов по СМС.

Проблема в том, что вы делаете запрос к API с IP адреса, отличающегося от того, с которого вы авторизованы во ВКонтакте. А т.к. у вас еще и не настроена двухфакторная авторизация, то ВКонтакте считает это подозрительным и запрещает обращаться к API от имени используемого вами аккаунта с «левого» IP-адреса. У меня было много аккаунтов и ни с одного я не мог обратиться к API со стороннего сервера без двухфакторной авторизации.

Очень печально, что отвратительная документация VK API вынуждает людей искать решение подобных незадокументированных проблем на Stack Overflow.

Comment: Почему недокументированных, вон даже прямо в ответе есть ссылка на документацию

Comment: @andreymal, я так полагаю, вы не читали содержимое той ссылки перед тем, как решили написать комментарий. Или очень невнимательно прочли мой ответ.

Comment: А что не так? В вопросе ошибка 17, в по ссылке ошибка 17, там же сказано, что надо открыть ссылку в браузере и всё решится. Как воюющий с этой ошибкой четыре последних года я подтверждаю, что открытие ссылки в браузере всё решает. Что ещё-то?

Comment: И да, двухфакторой аутентификации у меня нет и никогда не было, однако всё равно открытие ссылки в браузере помогало всегда бесперебойно

Comment: @andreymal, это потому, что вы запросы делаете с того же IP, с которого сами сидите во ВК. А автор пишет не standalone-приложение, а бота, которого едва ли будет держать на локальной машине. Сколько redirect_uri не открывайте — не поможет, потому что при открытии redirect_uri ВКонтакте запоминает IP-адрес, который открыл эту самую ссылку, и, собственно, именно для этого адреса снимает «заглушку» в виде 17-й ошибки.

Comment: Я тоже именно что пишу ботов, которые у меня работают на VDS-сервере, и эту ошибку я встречал именно там :)

Comment: В документации ВК написано, что для standalone-приложения (в нашем случае ботом является именно оно) для implicit flow авторизации [ключ может быть использован только для запросов непосредственно с устройства пользователя](https://vk.com/dev/access_token). Отсюда довольно очевидно, что все запросы должны отправляться с этого самого одного устройства, то есть с VDS-сервера (или где там автор ботов запускает). Так что не нужно гнать на документацию — там всё написано — а нужно ставить браузер на сервере и открывать ссылку там. Последние пару лет мои боты уже ни разу не сталкивались с этим :)